# Change OnClick to OnKeyUp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla, module

I don't have a lot of experience with PHP, JQuery, and Ajax. I'm trying to create a module in Joomla to work like https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp.

I've used something from ostraining on how to create a module for Joomla. The module I copied from them does pretty much exactly what I want. Returns links to articles based on the search box. The only issue it's not a live search, it's a submit.

This is the code that sends the xmlhttprequest:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function () {    
        var value = $('input[name=data]').val(),        
        request = {
            'option' : 'com_ajax',
            'module' : 'ajax_search',
            'data'   : value,
            'format' : 'raw'
        };
        $.ajax({
            type   : 'POST',
            data   : request,
            success: function (response) {$('.search-results').html(response);}
        });
        return false;
    });
})(jQuery)
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined

Further through the js file, I found this broken line

> g.send(b.hasContent && b.data || null),

And that is giving me a 404 error, so it's not receiving the request properly

Here is the modified code I'm trying to make work

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[name=data]').keyup(function() {
            var value   = $('input[name=data]').val(),
            request = {
                'option' : 'com_ajax',
                'module' : 'ajax_search_ver2',
                'data'   : value,
                'format' : 'raw'
            };
            $.ajax({
                type   : 'POST',
                data   : request,
                success: function (response) {$('.search-results').html(response);}
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
})(jQuery)
```

This code works and sends a request just fine. However, when I tried to convert it to `keyup` like the w3schools example, it has trouble with the request. I debugged the code with chrome developer tools and it gave me an error

I've seen responses before about "why didn't you just do this..." again I'm just a beginner here. I'm trying to understand the logic and how changing pretty much one line of code to take a submit button to a `keyup` event could break the `xmlhttprequest`. Any assistance is appreciated. If you need further input just let me know.

Comment: You're not setting a url..

Comment: Where  do you want sending data that url is missing in `$.ajax()` [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: But why does it send the url in the first code snippet?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, should I use 'GET' instead of 'POST'?